# Mock exception raised from class method with side effect gives 'did not raise'

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pytest, pytest-mock

Note: *This question is based on a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58842817/12367781) but modified to be different according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58843307/12367781)*.

Using [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock), I am trying to raise a `'URLError'` exception when a mock is called but I get a `DID NOT RAISE` error that I do not understand.

I have a `Query` class with a class method `make_request_and_get_response` which can raise several exceptions. I am **not** catching the `'URLError'` exception within the `get_response_from_external_api` method in `main.py`, so I *should* be able to expect to be raised and, subsequently, its exception mocked.

query.py

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import contextlib
import urllib

class Query:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.query = self.make_query()


    def make_query(self):
        # create query request using self.a and self.b
        return query


    def make_request_and_get_response(self):  # <--- the 'dangerous' method that can raise exceptions
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(self.query)) as response:
            return response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

main.py

```py
from foo.query import *

def get_response_from_external_api(query):
    try:
        response = query.make_request_and_get_response()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('Got a HTTPError: ', e)
    except Exception:
        print('Got a generic Exception!')
        # handle this exception


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    query = Query('input A', 'input B')
    result = get_response_from_external_api(query)
    return result
```

Using `pytest`, I am trying to mock that 'dangerous' method (`make_request_and_get_response`) with a side effect for a specific exception. Then, I proceed with creating a mocked `Query` object to use when calling the `make_request_and_get_response` with the expectation that this last call give a 'URLError' exception.

test_main.py

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
from foo.query import Query
from foo.main import get_response_from_external_api


class TestExternalApiCall:
    @patch('foo.query.Query')
    def test_url_error(self, mockedQuery):
        with patch('foo.query.Query.make_request_and_get_response', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
            with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
                q= mockedQuery()
                foo.main.get_response_from_external_api(q)
            assert excinfo.value = 'URLError'
            # assert excinfo.value.message == 'URLError' # this gives object has no attribute 'message'
```

The test above gives the following error:

```
>       foo.main.get_response_from_external_api(q)
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'> id='72517784'>") == 'URLError'
```

The same error occurs even if I catch the `'URLError'` exception and then re-raise it in `get_response_from_external_api`.

Can someone help me understand what I am missing in order to be able to raise the exception in a pytest?

---

**Update** according to @SimeonVisser's response:

If I modify `main.py` to remove the `except Excpetion` case:

```py
def get_response_from_external_api(query):
    try:
        response = query.make_request_and_get_response()
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print('Got a URLError: ', e)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print('Got a HTTPError: ', e)
```

then the test in `test_main.py`:

```py
    def test_url_error2(self):
        mock_query = Mock()
        mock_query.make_request_and_get_response.side_effect = Exception('URLError')
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            get_response_from_external_api(mock_query)
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

The test passes OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `get_response_from_external_api()` already catches an `Exception` and doesn't raise it to anywhere outside that function. So when you mock the query and make `make_request_and_get_response` raise an exception, it won't be seen by pytest because `get_response_from_external_api()` already catches it.

If you change it to be the following then pytest has a chance of seeing it:

```py
    except Exception:
        print('Got a generic Exception!')
        # handle this exception
        raise
```

The test case also doesn't appear to work as intended. It can be simplified to the following (it's a bit easier to create a mock query directly and pass that around):

```py
import pytest
from unittest import mock
from foo.main import get_response_from_external_api


class TestExternalApiCall:
    def test_url_error(self):
        mock_query = mock.Mock()
        mock_query.make_request_and_get_response.side_effect = Exception('URLError')
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            get_response_from_external_api(mock_query)
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

and then the test case passes (in addition to also making the above change with `raise`).

---

Response to question 1:

The difference is that you're mocking `Query` using the decorator but then you're mocking the class `foo.query.Query` inside the test case to raise that exception. But at no point does `mockedQuery` actually change to do anything differently for that method. So `q` is a regular instance of `mock.Mock()` without anything special.

You could change it to the following (similar to the above approach):

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
from foo.query import Query
from foo.main import get_response_from_external_api


class TestExternalApiCall:
    @patch('foo.query.Query')
    def test_url_error(self, mockedQuery):
        with patch.object(mockedQuery, 'make_request_and_get_response', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
            with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
                get_response_from_external_api(mockedQuery)
            assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

Your `with patch('foo.query.Query........` statement would work if anywhere in the code it then instantiated a `Query` instance from that location.

Response to question 2:

Hmm, I can't reproduce that - is the test case that you have locally the same as in the question? I had to modify it as `foo.main.get_response_from_external_api(q)` doesn't exist (`foo` isn't being imported) so I changed it to call `get_response_from_external_api(q)` and I keep getting:

```
>               get_response_from_external_api(q)
E               Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>
```

Comment: Forgot about the last catch-all `Exception`. Thank you for the explanation and the example code! Two follow-up questions: 1) could you possibly point out where was my error with the using-the-patch-decorator approach and the patch context manager compared to your mock-directly approach? 2) My test pass even if I *do not re-raise the 'URLError'; just by removing the `except Exception` case, it works. This is somewhat different to what you are saying, no?

Comment: Many thanks for your edited answer that discuss my follow-up questions. I have now updated my question to address your response to question 2.

Comment: @timmy78h yeah, if you use the test case as in my answer and then remove the `except Exception`, it'll indeed pass because it's on the mocked query object that `make_request_and_get_response` is being called and then the exception does get raised to outside the function (and then pytest notices and the test passes). So no surprises there; I don't see that behaviour with the test case in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to answer this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58898675/12367781